# How Do I See Which User/Group is Running My Django Application?

Tags: python, django, linux, bash

I am currently developing my Django loggers and I have a question when it comes to writing to a new file that has not been created yet.

I know Django is supposed to create the new file if it is not already there (the **log file**) and then write to it there. My issue is that, whichever user is running the Django application (presumably the one I launched it under, or even www-data?) does not have access to that directory.

How I got it to finally do as I needed, is I opened up the directory to be writable by all. This is, in my opinion very unsafe and definitely not wanted. I tried this to make sure my loggers were properly setup and it works as desired when I make this change.

I have since closed off those permissions and now I am back to square 1 until I find out a solution.

**Main Question**

How do I find out which user is running Django, or at least whatever it is that is trying to create the file, *in order to add them to a group that has write access to that directory*?

Comment: When you made the folder writeable by all and ran the app, who owned the newly created log file? That's the user running the django app.

Comment: Forgot to mention that, it was myself, which was weird. Because I have full writability to that directory, but without opening up the permissions, it wouldn't do it.

Comment: Are you using gunicorn? And if you are do you use a bash file to run it?

Comment: @onyeka yes! Except, this issue right now is on my development laptop so it’s running off the dec server from Django